# Stream.of_list with custom data types

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to define a new type of data, to create a list and then to create a stream out of the list:

```
type 'a myType =  Name of char ;;
let myList = [Name('a')];;
let myStream = Stream.of_list myList;;
```

Error: The type of this expression, '_a myType Stream.t,
       contains type variables that cannot be generalized

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code, `myStream` is a stream of type `myType` parametrized by an unknown type (which is called `'_a` in your error above). The compiler did not find enough information in your code about what `'_a` should be.

In some cases, the compiler would then generalize the type by stating that `'_a` can be anything. For instance, `myList` is properly identified as `'a myType list`. However, given that `Stream.t` is an abstract type, generalization might cause errors, so it is not performed.

One way to work around this is to specify the type of `'_a` if you only intend it to be used with a single type, for instance with a type constraint :

```
let myStream : int myType Stream.t = ...
```

Another way, if you wish to keep it generic, is to turn it into a function (which is then automatically generalized) :

```
let myStream () = Stream.of_list myList
```

The type will be `unit -> 'a myType Stream.t` as expected.

The underlying reason why such generalization might cause errors is the presence of mutable state. Suppose that I define four files as such:

```
(* ref.ml *)
let x = ref None

(* ref.mli *)
val x : 'a option ref

(* a.ml : 'a = string *)
Ref.x := Some "Hello"

(* b.ml : 'a = int *)
match !ref x with None -> () | Some i -> print_int i
```

This would cause a runtime error. As such, whenever mutable state is involved, types cannot be generalized.

Comment: Thank you!, it makes a lot of sense now. I remove the 'a and my user defined type has 3 different possible types.